# Diff. between required in HTML5 and required in jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I use jquery validation plugin for validation.all works perfect.
first i clarify some things:
(1) first i use required in textbox (not added jquery.js and jquery.validate.js), it works perfect.

```
 <input id="cname" name="name" type="text" required/>
```

(2) then i add jquery validation files and in textbox i already include `required` tag. it is also work.

`first quetion :`

The `required` tag is same for HTML5 and jquery validation  [(see example here)](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), so how they identify it and what is the diff. between it and which one is finally work?

`another quetion (only for jquery validation):`

if i add `class="required"` in textbox the jquery validation is still work

```
<input id="cname" name="name" type="text" class="required"/>
```

and also work for

```
<input id="cname" name="name" type="text" required/>
```

so what is the diff. between this two lines and why jquery validation is work in both case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 validations are dependant on browser. but if browser does not support html5 validation then you will need jquery validation to work there.

So, I would say, for now use jquery validation, and do not trust on html5 validation. because not all browser support this.

see this, which browser support html5 validation
[image]

Comment: ya true, but quetion is how they both identify using just one `required tag`? and i use finally jquery validation but i ask quetion for understand the working flow.

Comment: if you are using jquery validation, the `required` is read and jquery validation is configured, in that case html5 validation is kind of ignored.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and what about my second quetion. why jquery validation is working in this both cases : `required` and `class="required"`?

Comment: jquery same work for `required` ,`required=""` and `class='required'` for detail you can see the validation script file of jquery

Comment: thank you once again. your both comment gives my answers.so please update your answer.